why does the value of n increases by one in in first iteration while the result of (n+1)%26 is 0.26
in line 10, n = (n + 1) % 26;  the value of n should be 0.26 in first iteration as it has not been rounded up or rounded down so why has the value of n increased by one ?? I don't understand this part can any one explain? much appreciated.
// Function to shift each alphabet character in the input string to the next character in the alphabet
function alphabet_char_Shift(str) {
  var all_chars = str.split(""); // Convert the input string into an array of characters
  for(var i = 0; i < all_chars.length; i++) { // Iterate over each character in the array
    var n = all_chars[i].charCodeAt() - 'a'.charCodeAt(); // Calculate the position of the character in the alphabet
    n = (n + 1) % 26; // Shift the position to the next character in the alphabet, considering circular nature
    all_chars[i] = String.fromCharCode(n + 'a'.charCodeAt()); // Update the character with the shifted character
  }
  return all_chars.join(""); // Convert the array of characters back to a string and return
}

// Example usage
console.log(alphabet_char_Shift("abcdxyz"));


I very much doubt that n would ever by 0.26; n is an integer (namely, a position), and adding 1 and doing a modulo won't change that: the result will remain an integer.

So: why do you think it should be 0.26?

The point of that expression is the increment the value and reset to 0 after hitting 25. Modulo has nothing to do with percentages.

var n = all_chars[i].charCodeAt() - 'a'.charCodeAt();   isnt the value of this n zero in the first iteration ? if it is then,  n = (n+1) %26  is the same as n=(0+1) % 26 which would be 1%26 =0.22 ?

The initial value of n is a number representing how far into the alphabet the first character of str is (beginning with 'a' as 0.) I don't know where this value of 0.22 comes from unless that was a typo. But as already stated, the modulus operation doesn't do anything related to percentages. 1 % 26 evaluates to 1.

thank you shawnt00 and 9769953  . I was confused by the % sign . now that makes it clear.
